# how can i add all my tags to tagcloud?

Tags: tags

Hello i would like to show my all tags as a tagcloud . But i want to show all my tags some of them i added manually and they are not connected with any article?
Is there any way to do it

this code shows only tags which connected with the articles. i want to show all of them.

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => array( 'post_tag', 'category' ), 
    ); 

    wp_tag_cloud( $args );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll take a look at [`wp_tag_cloud` Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud#Default_Usage), then you'll se a list of all args that function takes.

On that list you'll see param called `number` that defines the maximal count of tags to show. It's default value is 45.

Later you can read that:

> `number` (integer) (optional) The number of actual tags to display in
>   the cloud. (Use '0' to display all tags.) Default: 45

So this should do the trick:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => array( 'post_tag', 'category' ), 
        'number' => 0
    ); 

    wp_tag_cloud( $args );
?>
```

Comment: its not what i want to have . my problem is i have some tags but they are not connected with the tags . i want to show all tags even its not connected with the topic

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what do you mean by “some tags not connected with tags”

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lhkr8o as you see there is a 3 tag and they are deneme, efsane, efsaneburda i have also some tags but they are not added like them . this what i meant :)